# Handle null condition (In sonar Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "false")

Tags: java, sonarqube

```
public boolean validateEmployeeRequestForm(String empCode) {
           if ( null == empCode ) {
                return false;
            }
           return true;
    }
```

Here on second line `if ( null == empCode )` it gives me `Sonar` exception below.

> Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "false".

How to handle it?

Comment: How/where is the method called? It is possible that 'validateEmployeeRequestForm' never gets 'null' as parameter? Did you consider empty strings?

Comment: do you actually set a value to that param before calling it? is that the actual code you are evaluating, or does it just "look like it" ?

Comment: I think the bigger problem is that the method does not return _any_ value if the `if` condition fails.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen might seem so, but no. This code won't compile, so it's not likely sonar will even look at it

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, I would expect this to not even compile.

Comment: yes it could be null or empty.

Comment: Just a note on naming: the name of your method is absolutely misleading. Why don't you call it "isNotNull()" or something alike? Yo see: the term **validation** probably means much more to 99% of all programmers than "see if null". And that is the point of good naming: it tells you what is going on; and doesn't leave room for surprises!

Comment: Can you show us all the calls to validateEmployeeRequestForm method ?

Comment: Have you shown us the entire method?  I suspect you've omitted some of it.  Are there some lines ABOVE this that rely on `empCode` being not null, such as a dereferencement of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public boolean validateEmployeeRequestForm(String empCode) {
       return empCode != null;
}
```